# Powershell Add-Type reference for class member type

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to add some code to my `profile.ps1` that lets me interact with some zip files full of xml files. I can do this in a shell manually and I don't need help with the reading process, but it doesn't work in my `profile.ps1`.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.IO.Compression","System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"

class DataPair
{
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]$archive
    [System.Xml.XmlDocument]$xmldoc
}
```

This is at the very top of my `profile.ps1` so I could share a `DataPair` object with named archive and xml document because some of the helper functions refer to other xml within the original archive.

When I go to load it either in command prompt shell or opening Powershell ISE, I get this error.

```
At C:\Users\rrobertson\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:5 char:6
+     [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]$archive
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive].
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

How do I fix this reference? Alternatively, is there a non-class option that would let me store these two values together in an easy reference format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently this is a known bug in the Powershell parser. The parser does not read assemblies loaded by `Add-Type` or `using assembly` but I was able to satisfy the parser by using the fully assembly qualified type name as in `[System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive, System.IO.Compression, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKey=b77a5c561934e089]`.

This also adds the assembly to the AppDomain so it is a workaround for now.